# Finding average length per line in a file using Python

Tags: python

I'm very beginner at Python. My question is as the title states, how would I write a function that would return the average line length in a file? (Not really sure how to incorporate files in functions) (Any help would help!)

Comment: .@spookyblack  What have you tried? What does your data look like?

Comment: @merlin I feel as though what I have is irrelevant as I am unsure how to calculate the length for each line, for any given amount of lines

Comment: @merlin how would I find the number of lines and divide it by the length?

Comment: You should put your code into your question and format it as code, so others can make sense of it

Comment: Is it a text file or a binary?

Comment: .@spookyblack. show you work, if this is homework say it's homework. We are here to help, not do homework for you.

Comment: @Merlin , it's practice for myself. This is a space where everyone is welcome. Please stop degrading me, a user you do not know of.

Comment: @spookyblack  If it was practice then you should have shown your work!

Comment: @spookyblack  Here is what need to do.   http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @spookyblack, a tutorial or two may be a good idea, http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pretty straightforward, sum the length of the lines then divide by the number of lines.

```
with open("testfile.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print(sum(len(line) for line in lines) / len(lines))
```

Comment: Doesn't the fact that OP refers to lines imply that it is text?

Comment: Thank you @Keatinge ! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Keatinge , I appreciate people like you (:

Comment: @Keating,  No, OP learnt that he can just come to SO, and  post, Have other people write code for them. This Q will be flagged as duplicate and deleted.

Comment: @Merlin And why is that a reason to downvote? http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down `an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.` You and I both know this code works

Answer (score 0):

if you have test.txt like:

```
line one text
line two text longer
line three text even longer
```

and the script test.py:

```
from __future__ import division

def average(lines):
    length = 0
    for l in lines:
        length = length+len(l)

    return int(length/len(lines))


with open('./test.txt') as f:
    my_lines = f.readlines()
    avg = average(my_lines)
    print avg
```

Then when you run

```
python test.py
```

you should get 21